# Where to make induction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I have read a exercise that states as follows;

Use induction to prove that

$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: \forall m \in \mathbb{N}: n<m \Rightarrow \exists r \in \mathbb{N}: n+r=m.$

Sugestion. Prove that the set $$B=\{n\in\mathbb{N}:\forall m \in \mathbb{N}:n<m \Rightarrow \exists r \in \mathbb{N}: n+r=m\}$$ is inductive.

My attempt was:

1. If n=1 and m is a natural such that $1<m$, then $(m-1)$ is a natural number. Now we have that $1 +(m-1)=m$.
2. Now suppose that for any fixed n, it follows that is m is a natural number, and if $n<m$, then exist an integer $z_0$ such that $n+z_0=m.$ (inductive hipothese).
3. Now we want to prove that for n+1, if m is a natural number, and $n+1<m$, then exist an integer z such that $(n+1)+z=m$.

But we have that $n+1<m$, then $n<m-1$ so for induction hypothese we have that exist z such that $n+z=m-1$ so $(n+1)+z=m$.

**BUT I don't know WHY we apply induction on n, and not on m. Is it wrong if I apply induction on m? Do I have to make induction on both n, and m?**

Also I want to know if the steps are right please. Im not sure if I stated the hipothese clear enough from the logic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If that's not your definition of $x<y$, you'll have to tell us what axioms you are allowed to use.

Comment: I believe you should have $\forall n,\forall m$.. (i.e. ',' rather than ':'). As  rough solution: make induction on $m$: if $m=1$ then $n=0$ and ... Then assume $m>1$ and assume the result holds for $m$. Then you have to show it for $m+1$ (in this case the $r$ will be the $r'+1$ where $r'$ is provided by the result with $m$). (Notice that I'm assuming that $0\in\mathbb{N}$ and that if $n+r=m$ then $n+r+1=m+1$. Check the axioms you should use..)

Comment: Are you allowed to use the division theorem?

Comment: We can use all real numbers properties according to the book.

Comment: i.e. least upper bound axiom, field axioms, and order axioms.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The question is a little bit "strange", because usually the formula $\exists x (m=S(x)+n)$ is the definition of $n < m$.

Thus, I suggest a tentative answer, based on induction on $n$.

i) *basis* : $n=1$

Thus, from $1 < m$, we have that $m=k+1$, for some $k$; thus $\exists r(m=r+1)$.

ii) *induction step* : assume that it holds for $n$ and prove it for $n+1$.

From $n+1 < m$, we have that $m=k+1$, for some $k$; thus $n+1 < k+1$, i.e. $n < k$.

We apply *induction hypotheses* to conclude that $\exists r(k=r+n)$, and from $k=r+n$ we have : $m=k+1=(r+n)+1=r+(n+1)$.

From this, we conclude that : $\exists r(m=r+(n+1))$.